# Why do the rules regarding typecasting and arithmetic operator as defined by introductory book seemingly clash?

Tags: java, operators, typecasting-operator

I recently started to learn java through a book catering towards programming beginners. Two rules regarding typecasting and arithmetic operators seem to clash logically and I just can't figure out where the problem lies.

Rule no. 1 as defined by the book: an int value is automatically typecast if it's assigned variable is of the types byte, short or char; e.g. short s = 1234; works without problems.

Rule no. 2 as defined by the book: if an arithmetic operator is used, the compiler first checks if one of the operands is of the type double, if this is the case then the other operand is automatically typecast to double. The same is repeated for float, then long and finally int.

My problem lies with a case like e.g.

```
short a = 1; 
short b = 2; 
short c = a+b;
```

I just don't understand why I would need to explicitly typecast, i.e. `short c = (short) (a+b)`; for this code to work. After all the above code should, according to rule 2, result in an integer value of 3 which should then be, according to rule 1, automatically typecast to short.

Any help or at the very least hints towards relevant, beginner friendly reading material would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's because `a` and `b` aren't compile time constants: try `final short a = 1; final short b = 2; short c = a+b;`

Answer (score 4):

It's because `a` and `b` aren't compile time constants.

This is called *implicit narrowing*, and is only allowed when the compiler can determine that the value being assigned to the variable fits into the range of that variable's type.

Try making the variables constant:

```
final short a = 1;
final short b = 2;
short c = a+b;  // Will now work.
```

You might wonder why the compiler doesn't already know that these are constants: this is just how the language is defined. For a variable to be considered compile-time constant, it has to be (amongst other requirements) explicitly final.

Comment: So to clarify: numbers that are directly assigned to variables are already considered constants while variables, unless they are final, are not considered constants and therefore aren't checked out by the compiler ? Is there any other way besides final to turn variables into constants ? Also, i guess for an entity to be a constant, ti has to be impssible to change them, which is why numbers and final fariables are constants ?

Comment: It's a bit more specific. The language spec says that ["A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), where a constant expression is [one of a number of specific types of expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), one of which is an int literal. Don't get too hung up on this if you're just beginning. Implicit narrowing is not very useful (because it only happens in very limited circumstances).

Comment: well i guess i'll cross that bridge once i know more than jsut "hello world". Thank you very much for having the patience to answer such a beginner question <3